# How to initialize onclick of multiple images by calling a function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pace two images in screen with their two separate counters above them. As well i am trying to make it modular and use a function which does initialization for onClick methods on the two images. However things does work out the way i expect. The two counters point to same memory location and clicking on any image retrieves the value from same counter.
How can i fix it and yet maintain the modularity?

.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text1"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image1">
<p id="text2"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image2">
<script>


function Counter(idText,idImage){
    var that = this;
    that.counter = 0;
    document.getElementById(idImage).onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById(idText).innerHTML = (++that.counter);
    };
}

var image1 = Counter("text1","image1");
var image2 = Counter("text2","image2");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `new` before Counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code `Counter("text1","image1");` will simply called that function, and its execution context will be `window`, so both of the image will use that `window.counter` as their counter.

So you need to add `new` to before `Counter`, which now will take `Counter` as a constructor, create a new object and then execute the code in `Counter`, while the `this` will be point to that newly created `object`. So both object will have their value independently.

In this case, the `image1` will be object, which has an attribute `counter`, so you can use `image1.counter` to access the counter value in other place.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text1"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image1">
<p id="text2"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image2">
<script>


function Counter(idText,idImage){
    var that = this;
    that.counter = 0;
    document.getElementById(idImage).onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById(idText).innerHTML = (++that.counter);
    };
}

var image1 = new Counter("text1","image1");
var image2 = new Counter("text2","image2");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Another way use `var counter = 0;` instead of `this.counter = 0`. Then when each of the image added a counter by the function, its click event handler will only see the `counter` declared in `Couter`. This is the [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) way.

In this case, the `var image1 = Counter("text1","image1");`, the `var image1`  is not necessary, you can just use `Counter("text1","image1");`, but if you still want some control over it, you can return somthing in `Counter` to control it. In this way, the user is only allowed to alter/see the values by functions you provided.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text1"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image1">
<p id="text2"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image2">
<script>


function Counter(idText,idImage){
    var counter = 0;
    document.getElementById(idImage).onclick = function(){
    // Now each image's handler will see the counter we just defined, 
    // And not get messed with other images that also call the `Counter` function.
    document.getElementById(idText).innerHTML = (++counter);
    };
  
    var setZero = function() {
      counter = 0;
      document.getElementById(idText).innerHTML = 0;
    };
    var shoutCount = function() {
      alert('You clicked on' + idImage+ ' ' + counter + 'times.');
    };
    return {
      setZero: setZero,
      shoutCount: shoutCount
    };
}

// If we want to have some control to image1 , but don't care other.
// Get the control's return by Counter call
var image1 = Counter("text1","image1"); 
// We don't want to control image2, simply call is ok.
Counter("text2","image2"); 
setTimeout(function() {
  image1.shoutCount();
  image1.setZero();
}, 3000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i guess new is needed for here too.

Comment: Just wondering... In your second example, is it even necessary to assign the result of `Counter()` to `var image1`? Are you able to just call `Counter()` by itself?

Comment: even without "new" works! simply Counter("text1","image1");
 Counter("text2","image2");   but why?!

Comment: @thelittlegumnut Yes you can.

Comment: @thelittlegumnut I've added in what case the `image1`, `image2` may be needed and also updated my answer.

Comment: @WaterfrVilla That is closure, you can find some detail at [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="text1"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image1">
<p id="text2"></p>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif" id="image2">
<script>

function getImage(idText,idImage){
    var newImage = new Object();
    newImage.counter = 0;
    newImage.onClick = function(){
        document.getElementById(idText).innerHTML = (++newImage.counter);
    };


    document.getElementById(idImage).onclick = newImage.onClick;

}

getImage("text1","image1");
getImage("text2","image2");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```